# Inherited forms, button alignments/anchoring not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, button

On my new screen I am inheriting a base form, which contains two buttons that come from the base.

In the middle of these two buttons I have placed a new button which resides on the new form and not the base.

Going on different resolutions, the positioning of the button changes compared to the two buttons which come from the base form.

[image]

Any ideas why it is reacting this way and how it can be changed?

All of the buttons are also anchored to the bottom right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You've anchored the buttons to the bottom of both forms?If that doesn't work for you try to use `TableLayoutPanel` to organize your form.

Comment: They are anchored exactly the same, ok ill try that now!